# What is the AWS Elastic Beanstalk server path for NSAppTransportSecurity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, parse-server

I migrated my ParseServer to AWS via **Elastic Beanstalk**. But I have a problem with *Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP*. I don't want to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` for this. If I change the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` boolean to `YES`. It's Ok. But I think this approach is not a best way. I want to use `NSExceptionDomains` so **How can I add my Elastic Beanstalk server address to** `Info.plist` ?

This is the my AWS Beanstalk server path:
http://parseserver-blabla-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

Answer (score 0):

Open `Info.plist` in source code mode to reveal the xml content. Then add the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourserver.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Having said that, I would not recommend you doing this. The ideal way is to register a domain name, get a SSL certificate for this domain and forward to your AWS elastic beanstalk address.

Comment: Yea, I am asking What is the Elastic Beanstalk domain to add NSExceptionDomains in my plist.

Comment: Ok get it from you AWS account if you want it to be specific to your sub-domain e.g. something.ap-something.elasticbeanstalk.com or just use elasticbeanstalk.com. Again, I would not recommend you doing this.

Comment: I tried but still same. I updated my question with AWS Path

Comment: @emresancaktar please help to migrate parse server to Elastic Beanstalk i'm new to AWS